# Second highest value for each id

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, zoho

I have a table with all the appointments information

| id_appoint | id_doc | app_date(d/m/y) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 201 | 30/10/22 |
| 16 | 202 | 20/10/22 |
| 15 | 203 | 19/10/22 |
| 14 | 204 | 18/10/22 |
| 13 | 201 | 30/09/22 |
| 12 | 202 | 20/09/22 |
| 11 | 203 | 19/08/22 |
| 10 | 204 | 18/07/22 |

what I'm trying to get is the second highest date for each doctor's appointment, for example
*THIS IS THE TABLE I WANT TO CREATE (I don't have this table)*
(I'm trying to use zoho analytics to introduce this query)

| id_appoint | id_doc | app_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 201 | 30/09/22 |
| 12 | 202 | 20/09/22 |
| 11 | 203 | 19/08/22 |
| 10 | 204 | 18/07/22 |

This doesn't work because it only excludes the highest date of the whole table

```
SELECT id_doc, MAX( app_date )
  FROM table1
GROUP BY id_doc
 WHERE col < ( SELECT MAX( app_date )
                 FROM table1 )
```

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the subquery correlated to the main query using a `WHERE` clause. And `GROUP BY` goes at the end.

```
SELECT id_doc, MAX( app_date )
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE col < (SELECT MAX( app_date )
            FROM table1 AS t2
            WHERE t2.id_doc = t1.id_doc)
GROUP BY id_doc
```

Or join with the subquery.

```
SELECT t1.id_doc, MAX(t1.app_date)
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id_doc, MAX(app_date) AS maxdate
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY id_doc
) AS t2 ON t1.id_doc = t2.id_doc AND t1.app_date < t2.app_date
GROUP BY t1.id_doc
```